# Custom CSS working on any browser except MEdge

Tags: css, wordpress, microsoft-edge

My shop's list view breaks in MEdge only. Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

The website can be found [here](http://hsushi3.haikusushi.bg/shop/).

And the Custom CSS I am using to arrange the images is the following.

```css
/*WooCommerce Shop Button Alignment*/
.woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product {
    min-height: 270px !important; 
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.woocommerce ul.products li.product .button {
    margin-top: 0;

}
/*WooCommerce Shop image aligning*/
.list-view {
    display:flex;
}
.item-img {
    display:inherit !important;
    align-items:center !important;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
.actions-addtocart a {
    line-height:33px !important;
}

/*hiding customlocation class */
.cart-customlocation {
    display:none;
}
```

I believe that for some reason Edge doesn't recognise part of the custom CSS.

I have cleared cache as well and that doesn't seems to fix it either.

Comment: If edge doesn't understand that css it's worst than i thought.

Comment: Also, try these options: A) Open page in incognito mode B) Launch Edge with clean profile.